# What's behind the FXCop rule CA1061 "Do not hide base class methods"?

Tags: overriding, fxcop

Why is the FxCop rule [CA1061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182143(VS.80).aspx) a bad idea?

The docs state that this rule should not be suppressed.  If I have class like so:

```
public class Set<T>
{    List<T> m_backingList;

     public bool Contains(T value)
     {
         return m_backingList.Contains(value);
     }
}
```

then I add a specific implementation like this:

```
public class CaseInsensitiveSet : Set<String>
{
    public bool Contains(object value)
    {
         string stringValue  = value as string;
         if (stringValue == null)
             return false;
         return base.Contains(stringValue);
    }
}
```

the FxCop complains, but I'm not certain why this is such a bad idea.  Is there some problem I don't see with this implementation?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you accept an object in the contain's method. Why not take in a string?

Comment: @RichardOD, indeed why not just take a string.  I assume it's a convenience method so that you can test anything to see if it is in the set, otherwise the calling code would have to be responsible for checking that the things given are strings.  I really wanted to know why in this instance this is a bad idea.

Comment: What you have there is something that I like to call the "One sided contract" antipattern.  The contract between the called code and the calling code places an undue burden on one participant of the contract, in this case the called code.  It isn't reasonable for your `CaseInsensitiveSet` to pretend to accept an object when the only thing that it can actually work with is strings.  Instead, use the method interface to state the contract explicitly: `Contains()` only works with strings. (It's trivially easy for the client code to replicate this behavior by using "as" in the method call.)

Comment: Additionally, based on what your code appears to do, why not just use this- HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule states why you're getting the message:

> A method in a base type is hidden by
>   an identically named method in a
>   derived type when the parameter
>   signature of the derived method
>   differs only by types that are more
>   weakly derived than the corresponding
>   types in the parameter signature of
>   the base method.

In your child class, the Contains method takes an `object` which is more weakly typed than `string` and therefore hides the parent.

The reason you're getting the warning from FxCop is that this might not be an intentional design choice (since you're not overriding anything or using the `new` keyword).

Even if it is an intentional design choice, I would argue that it's not necessarily a good one. If you already know that the collection is going to contain strings and nothing else, why would you provide a `Contains` method that takes anything other than a `string`? It may appear that you're adding flexibility into the design but, in the end, you're really only going to confuse other developers.

There are also other naming options instead of calling the method `Contains` which wouldn't hide (intentionally or not) the base Contains method.

Comment: Thanks. Even if I use the new keyword (which it lets me do) it still complains.  So in the above example (with or without the new) would I be ok to ignore the warning or will I get suspect behaviour because of this somewhere down the line?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182143(VS.80).aspx

> A method in a base type is hidden by
>   an identically named method in a
>   derived type when the parameter
>   signature of the derived method
>   differs only by types that are more
>   weakly derived than the corresponding
>   types in the parameter signature of
>   the base method.

**EDIT**

Basically you're hiding the base method (public bool Contains in Set), which will never now be run in preference to the derived method.  But the derived method is more weakly defined than the base method so there are situations when the base method is the preferable method.

Comment: thanks. I had read the page that I linked to in the question.

Comment: @Sam Sorry if that seemed a bit cheap, but I had to unexpectedly do some work in between posting the MSDN answer and offering some additional comments.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself: do I want the users to be able to call the base class method on an instance of the derived class.
If the answer is yes: don't hide the base method, as this will make it more cumbersome to use it.
If the answer is no: don't derive from this class, or else they can still access the base method by casting the object to the base class.